# emacs rgrep in multiple sub directories

Tags: emacs, grep, find

I want to grep in multiple sub directories, eg.

> find subdir1 subdir2 -type f ( -name *.cc -o -name *.h ) -exec grep -e someString {} +

using emacs interactive rgrep.  Is this possible?  The rgrep in grep.el says:

[image: rgrep]

but when I get to the "Base directory:" input, I can't figure out how to input more than 1 directory.
Is it possible to input more than 1 directory?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass prefix arguments to `rgrep` to modify the command.

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep` will take you through the normal prompts and then let you edit the result, at which point you can simply add the additional directories you wish to search to the initial `find` command.

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep` just gives you a bare template to edit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the files are in sub-directories of a project, you might consider using the emacs [projectile](https://projectile.mx/) module.  It handles multi-directory searching quickly and painlessly within a project.